# Why does Octopress require the Sinatra gem?

Tags: rubygems, sinatra, rack, octopress

I'm currently getting started with [Octopress](http://octopress.org/) and just cloned the repo. I noticed in the Gemfile that it requires the Sinatra gem.

Why does Octopress need Sinatra? I assume it's only for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's Used for Previews

At the time of this writing, Octopress has a [:preview rake task](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/blob/master/Rakefile) that [invokes rackup](https://github.com/rack/rack#rackup), which in turn [invokes Sinatra](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/blob/master/config.ru). Sinatra is used to serve up the pages on your localhost for viewing.